# How to print a string with a little delay between the chars?

Tags: python

I want a text to be displayed as if it is just being typed. So I need a little delay after every letter.

I tried to do it this way:

```
import time

text = "Hello, this is a test text to see if all works fine."
for char in text:
   print char,time.sleep(0.2),
```

It works fine, except for one problem. I get a "None" after every character.

This is the output:

```
H None e None l None l None o None , None   None t None h None i None s None   None i None s None   None a None   None t None e None s None t None   None t None e None x None t None   None t None o None   None s None e None e None   None i None f None   None a None l None l None   None w None o None r None k None s None   None f None i None n None e None . None
```

I don't know why this happens. I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Why are you printing the value of `time.sleep(0.2)`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> import time
>>> import sys
>>> blah = "This is written slowly\n"
>>> for l in blah:
...   sys.stdout.write(l)
...   sys.stdout.flush()
...   time.sleep(0.2)
...
This is written slowly
```

Comment: +1 for `flush()`. Of course, if you really want it to appear typed, the timing of the pauses should be random; who types at a perfectly regular pace?

Comment: Depends on the typist. Home keyed touch typists: the delay is going to be greater between same finger keys.. and probably shortest between alternating hands. Longer delay for shifting, etc. I started coding something up, but then decided to get back to work :)

Comment: @Wooble It depends. For example, I tend to type at a more or less regular speed, (...) with occasional breaks (...) to think about what I am going to type next.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the result of `time.sleep(0.2)`, which is `None`.  Move it to the next line.

```
text = "Hello, this is a test text to see if all works fine."
for char in text:
    print char,
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Of course, you still have the problem of a space between each character, which can be solved by replacing the `print` statement with a call to `sys.stdout.write`.

```
text = "Hello, this is a test text to see if all works fine."
for char in text:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: For Python 3, use `print(char, end="", flush=True)` in the 1st example.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `time.sleep` in a separate line. With a comma, you are printing its return value as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the return value of time.sleep(0.2) which is None.  Put it on a separate line.  The comma after "print char" will prevent a newline from being printed but it will introduce a single space after each character.

Try this instead:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import time
>>> text = "Hello, this is a test text to see if all works fine."
>>> for char in text:
...     sys.stdout.write(char)
...     time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: MattH beat me to the punch and also correctly included the flush() call.

Answer (score 1):

Your example prints them all on separate lines I think (at least on windows). You can use printing to `sys.stdout` to get around this.

```
import time, sys
for character in text:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
print char, time.sleep(0.2)
```

decodes as "print the value of `char`, and then print the return value of the function `time.sleep()` (which is `None`)".

You can break them onto separate lines, but the default behavior of `print` followed by a comma will leave you with spaces between the characters that you probably don't want. If not, look up how to change the behavior of `print`, or do something like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import time
>>> for char in "test string\n":
...    sys.stdout.write(char)
...    time.sleep(0.2)
...
test string
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help, this is my final code, I made a random timing for the delay as mentioned by Wooble:

```
import time
import sys
from random import randrange

text = "This is the introduction text."

for c in text:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    seconds = "0." + str(randrange(1, 4, 1))
    seconds = float(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
```